# How can I mock the value of sys.platform in python

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

My aim is to mock the value of sys.platform in python to be linux instead of win32 for my unittests. I found that some people use mock.patch but that does not change the value of sys.platform for the rest of execution of the python session.

Is there any way to mock that value for ever in the python session?

Thanks

Solution:
I found the solution to this problem. The issue was that I was mocking sys.platform in one script and in another I was importint platform from sys. That is not the same thing for python and I was getting another value for the platform.

The way I solved this was by mocing the whole path to platform:
module_1.submodule_1.platform = mock.MagicMock(return_value='whatever')

Comment: Why not run it in actual Linux? You are very likely to have it pass all your unit tests, but break the second you switch platforms due to the platform specific binaries python relies on simply not being available for win32. It is surprisingly easy to install docker and set up a simple `Dockerfile` which can be run to create a container (basically a lightweight VM) and run a few commands in it. https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: I considered this option but we have a machine in jenkins with our whole test setup and I would like to run the unit tests there. It is just a mere question of simplicity, we are testing an embedded software and we just want to test logic paths. But I might reconsider the docker option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for, here is how I was able to mock the platform (running on Mac):

**myfunc.py**

```
import sys

# function that I am testing
def print_os():
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        return "We are Windows"
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        return "We are Darwin"
    elif sys.platform == "linux":
        return "We are Linux"
```

**myfunc_test.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import myfunc


@patch('sys.platform', 'linux')
class TestOS(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_print_os(self):
        self.assertEqual(myfunc.print_os(), "We are Linux")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**testing:**

```
$ python -m unittest -v myfunc_test.py
test_print_os (main_test.TestOS) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want BUT I cannot make it run in my script. I'm using pytest and asyncio modules in my project and what I am testing is running a coroutine from another module that requires an specific OS. I want to fake the OS cause I just want to test the logic of the program, not the functionality but when I run the coroutine, the platform is win32 again! It's driving me crazy

Comment: I found the solution and your answer inspired the solution, thanks for it